# how to use QraphQL without local cache in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, graphql, cache-control

Problem is that I need to fetch data from the server, but it returns local cache data. So it has a different value from the server.

```
  final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink("URL");

  final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
        getToken: () => "Token", headerKey: "auth"
  );

  final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

  GraphQLClient  client = GraphQLClient(
      cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
      link: link,
    );

 ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> notifierClient = ValueNotifier(client);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `GraphQLClient` without `store`.

```
GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(
  cache: GraphQLCache(),
  link: link,
);
```